# Change key in dictionary serially in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Here I make a simple dictionary: the keys are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... I want to pop a key value.

```
dic = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

```
dic.pop(3)
```

The output is

```
dic = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

But I dont want this output. I want to change my dictionary key serially. like

```
dic = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}
```

I am new so please help me how can do it dynamically.

Comment: Won't `dic.pop(5)` achieve that? Also what do you mean by changing dictionary key `serially`?

Comment: Sounds like  you want ordered elements, keyed by a number, and to be able to remove arbitrary elements and have the structure adjust — seems like you want a list instead of a dictionary.

Comment: So after you pop 3, the key 3 is still in the dictionary? In what world does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
dic = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
def pop_keys(key):
    keys=[val for val in dic]
    values=[val for val in dic.values()]

    values.remove(dic.get(key))
    return {k:v for k,v in zip(keys,values)}
print(pop_keys(3))
```

Comment: hello, in your solution this line {k:v for k,v in zip(keys,values)} is confusion for me. what is normal for loop for that line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have sequential integer keys, you would be better using a list, but if you prefer to use a dictionary:

```
items = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
items.pop(3)
items = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(items.values(), start=1)}

print(items)
# Outputs {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}
```

Comment: Hello Enzo could you write normal for loop of
items = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(items.values(), start=1)}.    I am novice in programming language. Please